# sql commands to add a field to a table

Tags: sql

I am trying to use SQL commands to add a field called Birthday to a Customers Table. My command is

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD COLUMN Birthday
```

I keep getting a syntax error in the field definition. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to tell it what datatype to use for the new column

Comment: Pls show the code that is causing the error and specify the Database (SQL Server, MySQL, etc. in the tag (at least).

Answer (score 2):

The query need datatype for `birthday`, Ex:

```
 ALTER TABLE Customers ADD COLUMN Birthday datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specity type for your column. Assuming Birthday of type `DATETIME` and `NOT NULL`, The syntax for adding column is:

```
ALTER TABLE  Customers
ADD Birthday DATETIME NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional column `Birthday` must have it's `datatype`, such as `DATE`, `DATETIME` etc.

```
ALTER TABLE Customers 
ADD COLUMN Birthday DATETIME
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a type for the Birthday field.  The syntax may depend on what the type is and which version of SQL you are using (you haven't specified either).  Assuming you're using Microsoft SQL, and given that it's a birthday (and you don't need a time), and there are likely customers for whom you won't have a birthday, I'd recommend:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers 
ADD COLUMN Birthday DATE CONSTRAINT Customers_Birthday_Default DEFAULT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter TABLE Customers 
ADD Birthday DATETIME
GO
update Customers set Birthday = GETDATE()
GO

alter TABLE Customers
alter column Birthday DATETIME NOT NULL
GO

alter table Customers add constraint df_Customers_note default (getDATE()) for Birthday
GO
```